# Does Russia still need Prigozhin to manage and lead Wagner?

Tags: russian-federation, private-military-companies, wagner-pmc

> According to the Financial Times, the Wagner Group does not exist as a
> single incorporated entity, but instead as a "sprawling network of
> interacting companies with varying degrees of proximity to
> [Prigozhin's] Concord group" – such as Concord Management and
> Consulting and Concord Catering. This abstruse structure has allegedly
> complicated efforts by western governments to restrict Wagner's
> activities.[118]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner_Group

Does Russia still need Prigozhin to manage and lead Wagner? I was thinking that after the coup Russia would just seize his assets and manage his sprawling operations, but then I realized it was a really complex networks of companies that would be difficult to manage. So does Russia need Prigozhin still and for what reasons?

Comment: This question has not aged well...

Answer (score 8):

> **Question:**
>
> Does Russia still need Prigozhin to manage and lead Wagner?

If you look at where Prigozhin came from:

- penitentiary
- street hot dog salesman
- grocer
- casino owner
- Putin's caterer
- government contractor
- war lord
- oligarch
- billionaire.

Prigozhin's rise and utility has nothing to do with Russia's needs but rather Putin's needs.

What are those needs?  In May 2014, Prigozhin's Wagner group was one of the "private" armies which Putin used to disavow responsibility for the invasion of Ukraine.  This model has been useful for Putin in pseudo masking his involvements in Ukraine, Middle East and Africa.  But really Putin top concern, above all is to stay in power.  This is a service a well behaved Prigozhin aids him with.  The largest risk to Putin's power center is the Russian Army.  The organization, resources, and potential for independence to a politically and economically weakened Putin is the greatest threat to Putin's grip on power.   Real or imaginary they are the only group who could unseat a diminished Putin given growing unrest and ongoing cost of an expensive Ukrainian adventure.  Prigozhin helps him with this problem.  He taunts the Russian military, runs down their credibility, and diminishes them as an alternative to Putin.  Prigozhin attacks their senior leadership, and attacks their institutions while remaining silent and even deferential to Putin.  This is his real service beyond but linked to his façade of independence.

Is he replaceable, certainly.  He is a Putin creature who can only act/exist with Putin's support.  His reputation, credibility and accomplishments are entirely due to Putin.  When Prigozhin is killed either by Putin or by the Russian Army, we will probable see a clone take on his role.   While I think the west is growing wise to the pseudo private Russian army adventurism,  Prigozhin's utility as a foil against the Russian military remains a helpful insurance policy for Putin whos greatest fear has always been being gunned down in the streets like Muammar Gaddafi by his own people.

> **From Comments:**
>
> Also, insofar as you imply Putin is playing off Wagner against the regular forces (rather than only trying to deal with their separate existences), that's an extraordinarily dangerous game to be playing when losing the war Putin triggered (as might be the natural consequence of playing off his own forces against each other instead of the enemy), means the Hague for Putin. Such political machinations may partly explain why Wagner came to exist separately from the regular forces, but it cannot possibly explain what is now going on, unless Putin is more frightened of his generals than the gallows

I don't think Putin is frightened by the Hague at all.  It's not like the Hague has an army.  It's not like any European or American leader would use military assets against Russia to enforce the Hague's indictment.  The Hague is a long term concern, especially if he is displaced and no longer has the resources of Russia to hide behind.  Putin isn't losing sleep over not being able to attend the last BRICS conference in South Africa.  The far greater worry for Putin is domestic unrest.  I think that's Putin's immediate and primary concern.

As for What is going on now?  Wagner is in Belarus, massing on the Polish boarder having already conducted at least 1 incursion.  With the US Ambassador to the U.N. officially informing Russia that any attack by Wagner forces on Poland would be interpreted as a direct attack by Russia on NATO.

**[US warns Wagner attack on NATO will be treated as Russian attack](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/world/us-warns-wagner-attack-on-nato-will-be-treated-as-russian-attack/2958778)**

> I can't help thinking the logic in this answer doesn't make sense as a whole. You say: "This model has been useful for Putin in pseudo masking his involvements in Africa.". ***Masked from who exactly?*** Surely the more plausible explanation is that it allows Putin a relatively expendable fighting force - including people who won't or couldn't be regular soldiers - without committing Russian regular troops? It also allows the troops to be trained and experienced in battles which don't necessarily concern the Russian state one way or the other, to be ready for employment later for Russian purposes.

I don't think Wagner is an expendable fighting force so much as a deniable force which employs an expendable component.   Wagner is Russia's most effective unit.  They are veterans from the Russian army who now work as well paid mercenaries.  They are not conscripts or the folks who "need experience or seasoning".   The Prisoners who Wagner employs as cannon fodder are not representative of Wagner.  It is Wagner's accomplishments that put teeth in Prigozhin's taunts against the regular Army.  The prisoners/conscripts jobs are to stand in front of the vets and take the fire and set off the mines while Wagner waits for the real battle to commence after the defenses are diminished.

So I don't think Wagner is so much "expendable" as they are deniable.  That era however is coming to an end.  They have consistently acted in concert or in the direct interest of Putin, with his military and logistical support.  They are incapable of acting independently and that is recognized by the west.  Yet Wagner's pseudo "independence" has been an effective ploy for Putin, which helped disrupt the west forming a consensus opinion on how to respond to Russia's passed aggressions.

In 2014 Putin flat out denied sending troops over the boarder into Ukraine.  I think many understood Russia was invading but those who favored continued lucrative trade ties with Russia and their were many,  it gave them the fig leaf to continue business as usual for another 8 years.  Europe for example continued a billion dollar a day natural gas and oil import relationship with Russia until well into the second invasion.  Nord Stream II progressed and was even put into service(barely) between the first and second Ukrainian invasions.

In tampering with the 2016 US Election which Prigozhin was indicted for by a Washington DC grand jury in Feb 2018.  Russia claimed no involvement and their was no significant US reaction.

In Syria Feb 2018 when a handful of US special forces supporting Kurdish allies defending Conoco Oil Fields came under attack by 200 Wagner Troops,  the U.S. made use of dedicated deconfliction lines of communication set up to minimize the chances of Russians killing Americans or visa versa.  The Russians replied to several American queries they had no troops in the area.  The US forces heavily outnumbered on the ground called in the Airforce and the result was more Russian casualties at the hands of the US than the entire span of the Cold war.  The attack an attempt to seize a valuable oil field and murder US forces disavowed by Russia.  Beyond the battle, no appreciable response by the U.S.

Comment: I can't help thinking the logic in this answer doesn't make sense as a whole. You say: *"This model has been useful for Putin in pseudo masking his involvements in Africa."*. Masked from who exactly? Surely the more plausible explanation is that it allows Putin a relatively expendable fighting force - including people who won't or couldn't be regular soldiers - without committing Russian regular troops? It also allows the troops to be trained and experienced in battles which don't necessarily concern the Russian state one way or the other, to be ready for employment later for Russian purposes.

Comment: Also, insofar as you imply Putin is playing off Wagner against the regular forces (rather than only trying to deal with their separate existences), that's an extraordinarily dangerous game to be playing when losing the war Putin triggered (as might be the natural consequence of playing off his own forces against each other instead of the enemy), means the Hague for Putin. Such political machinations may partly explain why Wagner came to exist separately from the regular forces, but it cannot possibly explain what is now going on, unless Putin is more frightened of his generals than the gallows

Comment: I'd say right now, any Wagner actions can be downplayed by Putin even more than they were previously. Thus, getting them to "independently" make some diversionary incursions into Poland dilutes the West's attention to what he's "officially" doing in Ukraine. The US has obviously seen through all of that, but it remains to be seen if the rest of NATO agrees - and anything other than a fully aligned NATO gives Putin possible avenues of advantage. In some sense, he's testing NATO's political resolve against Russia without definitely triggering a military response.

Comment: @RalphBolton,  I don't think Putin has the stones to directly confront NATO.   What he's doing is a mock confrontation.  Pushing as far as he can without stepping over the line in an attempt to raise the pressure on NATO.  Putin hopes this will empower the doves in NATO to besiege Ukraine on behalf of a negotiated settlement which will allow Russia to keep Crimea.

Comment: @RalphBolton, We have all seen what happens when hundreds of Wagner troops  without air cover go up against a hand full of western soldiers with air cover.   Neither Putin nor Prigozhin want a repeat of the Conoco Oil Fields Battle.   Putin has a more realistic plan for pressuring Poland than sending Wagner over the boarder.  He's trying to inspire fear and thus political pressure.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, yes, at least in the short term.

Wagner - not [Concord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concord_Management_and_Consulting) - is not just "a company".  It is a military organization, operational during times of war.  Throughout history, combat soldiers have often formed special bonds with their leaders (ex:  Caesar and the Rubicon crossing).

[Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/investigates/special-report/ukraine-crisis-russia-wagner/) had an article in which wounded ex-cons, not those best-treated by Wagner, expressed intense loyalty towards Prigozhin.

Numerous articles have been written saying that few Wagner veterans expressed the intent to transfer to MoD and there has been limited observations of this happening in practice.

Senior Russian officers, ex:  Surovikin have at times spoken highly of Prigozhin.

Contrast that with the frequent criticism leveled at Shoigu and Gerasimov, in the context of an ill-fought war for which they are the principal figureheads and the rampant corruption in Russian military procurement.  For better or worse, Prigozhin does seem to want to equip his troops as well as he can (whereas the central government outsources much of that to the regions).

Not sure what Russia's long terms intents are wrt Wagner.  But how much can they afford to make do without one of their more effective force groupings?

ISW had something about that as well [today](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-august-9-2023):

> Putin is likely still concerned about the threat that Prigozhin poses to his long-term goals and continues to focus on definitively separating Prigozhin from Wagner. Putin has previously attempted to present Prigozhin as corrupt and a liar to destroy his reputation among Wagner personnel and within Russian society and to rhetorically separate Prigozhin from Wagner.[7] ISW assessed on June 27 that the Kremlin would likely continue to attack Prigozhin’s character to break Prigozhin’s popular support, discourage Wagner personnel from following him to Belarus, and destroy his financial power.[8] Putin’s June 29 meeting with Prigozhin and 35 Wagner commanders further indicated that Putin intends to maintain the Wagner Group as a cohesive fighting force rather than breaking it up while also seeking to separate Prigozhin from Wagner leadership and forces.

So, while they probably would love to do without him, they are not at all there yet.

Last, the proof is in the pudding.  If Prigozhin wasn't needed, he wouldn't still be [attending meetings in Russia with Wagner](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-66154909).

(None of this is intended in any way, shape or form, to support [Prigozhin](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/sledgehammer-execution-russian-mercenary-who-defected-ukraine-shown-video-2022-11-13/).  It is only to answer the question, in sharp contrast with the claims of the other answers).

p.s. I'd still stick to low buildings if I were Prigozhin though.

Comment: You did not advise him to not to fly....

Comment: I should have indeed been more open ended:  don't go up from ground level.  don't drink tea.  don't walk around Moscow.  don't drive or get into a car.  The world is just very unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

The web of companies only makes things difficult to trace when the law is intentionally arranged by the state to make things difficult to trace, for the benefit of the capitalist class.

In other words, Prigozhin's web of companies exists to resist sanctions and legal attacks by using the West's own lax traceability standards against it.

Western capitalists won't want their own tax havens and crooked transfers laid bare to democratic view, so that is why traceability won't improve until the West is openly at war and seriously threatened.

The corporate web isn't designed to protect Prigozhin from the Russian state, which anyway is his largest funder (so if they want to hurt his finances, they'd simply cut off his supply in the first place).

As to why Putin needs Prigozhin, it's because Prigozhin is the head of a large and effective body of armed fighting men, and Putin has a war to fight.

Putin could seize any Wagner bureaucracy by force, but he can't simply seize the trust and loyalty that Prigozhin enjoys. At best such seizure may simply destroy Wagner as a useful thing. At worst, it could put them back on the road to Moscow!

The challenge Putin has is not destroying Prigozhin or Wagner, it is integrating them with the regular armed forces in order to improve overall cooperation and coordination.

The problem arises because Putin has allowed Wagner to develop in parallel to the Russian armed forces, instead of keeping things together all along.

Western liberals like to fantasise that Putin is now burning with rage against Prigozhin - that sounds like wishful thinking.

I'm sure Putin is seriously annoyed by the Moscow march and all the political complications it causes, but the point is still to harness Prigozhin and Wagner for the benefit of the Russian state and its war effort.

Comment: Besides voicing your own biases what does the sentence "Western liberals like to fantasise that Putin is now burning with rage against Prigozhin - that sounds like wishful thinking." add to this comment? Do you have any reference to support that this view is particularly held by "liberals" rather than any other group? Better to stick to provable facts, if you can.

Comment: @LioElbammalf, firstly they are the main supporters of this war, and secondly you can sample their fantasies by reading the so-called mainstream media which is their stronghold. I mentioned it here to reinforce the point that Putin has a war to fight, and to counter the implication of the question that Putin is trying to dispense with Prigozhin or is otherwise engaged in some kind of petty power struggle with him. What Putin is actually trying to do is moderate competition and fold Wagner into the regular armed forces (having allowed them to exist separately). (1/2)

Comment: Prigozhin's march meanwhile is a show of strength and anger against his perceived political opponents in those regular forces, and he obviously enjoyed popular support everywhere that counts. Putin is obviously satisfied that Prigozhin's motives were honourable and his grievance somewhat genuine, and that he remains reasonably trustworthy, otherwise Prigozhin could not have survived the climbdown. There's simply no reason for Putin to get rid of a successful military commander, if you don't start from the idea there is some kind of vendetta. (2/2)

Comment: again you've got some opinions in there and a bit of conjecture. Support for the war doesn't mean they fantasise about Putin burning with rage. As it stands your answer, and comments, contain much more emotive language and biases than is useful. If you have a point you can prove some evidence would be welcome. Without it it's just your opinion and probably best left out of the stackexchange format.

Comment: In what way has Putin shown agreement with any of Prigozin's grievances? It's my understanding that shortly after the march on Moscow Putin has reaffirmed his support for Gerasimov and Shoigu (Russian military top) while Prigozin has had to pack up as a fighting force in Ukraine and some of [Prigozin's military allies have been detained (e.g. general Surovikin)](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2023/07/13/dozens-of-senior-russian-officers-detained-fired-after-wagner-mutiny-wsj-a81830).

Comment: @LioElbammalf, the idea that Putin intends to take revenge on Prigozhin, and that Putin is a man known for revenge, is a claim often heard. Anyway, I've explained the logic of why the answer takes the form it does.

Comment: @JJJ, backing his own generals or ministers in the context of Prigozhin marching on Moscow, isn't inconsistent with Putin acknowledging Prigozhin's grievances in his own mind. For example, Prigozhin accused the regular forces of starving him of necessary resources. Crowds cheered Prigozhin and he seemingly had the support of a swathe of the regular forces (including as you say Surovikin), so it can't be a singular delusion on Prigozhin's part. Sending Prigozhin to Belarus and telling Surovikin to make himself invisible is frankly the mildest possible measures.

Comment: I looove how Russia's mercenary's issues are "the Western capitalists faults".  -1 for going off on a side rant rather than answering the question:  "does Russia still need Prigozhin?".  How much of that is there in this answer?  Vanishingly little seems like.  Western corporate ownership structure aren't that relevant, in Russia.  Neither is this supposed Western liberal fantasy.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, actually I said the *web of companies* were "the Western capitalists faults"! It was precisely my point that these webs don't exist because they are necessary in Russia or because they protect Prigozhin against Putin, they exist as a card trick to play against the West, who use the same tricks to hide their own dirty money, and whose legal and accounting framework is therefore set up to allow that hiding of dirty money in this way. Swiss banks, nominee accounts, cryptocurrencies, yes please!